# JavaScript my function to test a password doesn't work

Tags: javascript, regex

```
function demoMatchClick() {
  var validString = /^[a-z](?=[a-z]*[0-9])[a-z0-9]{0,6}[a-z]$/
  var re = new RegExp(validString);
  if (document.form1.subject.value.test(re)) {
    alert("Successful match");
  } else {
    alert("No match");
  }
}

<INPUT TYPE=SUBMIT VALUE="Replace" ONCLICK="demoReplaceClick()">
```

I can't get it to popup an Alert to pop up

I want these rules to be enforced

```
•Not have upper-case letters. 
•Begin with a letter. 
•Have at least 1 digit(s) not at the beginning and end. 
•Have up to 8 alphanumeric 
•Does NOT have any symbols like @#$ characters (symbols like !@#$%^&*()-+).
```

I am using a button to execute the code for now.

Comment: You can't get either alert to pop up? Where are you calling `demoMatchClick()`?

Comment: Try a Javascript regexp sandbox such as http://regexpal.com/. Also, why are you doing `new RegeExp` when `validString` is already a regexp?

Comment: Your rules are pretty bad from a security standpoint. You're telling an attaccker that the first character is for sure a letter, that the password does't end with a digit and all characters are lowercase. And the maximum length is just 8 characters. It's broken. Let the user have lengthy passwords with no enforcements, is more secure (require just a minimum length, really).

Comment: I don't think `demoMatchClick()` is being called if you're not getting *any* alerts. Please show more code/html.

Comment: Riccardo Galli is right. All you are doing with those requirements is restricting the number of combinations possible making it easier for a hacker to find the password.

Comment: [XKCD](http://xkcd.com/936/) has pretty much summed up the omnipresent misconceptions about password security.

Comment: I didn't create these rules. The client has these rules and refuses to change them. So they want me to write a script to help their employees determine if their password matchines these rules!

Comment: @CocoaDev Sad, but typical story, alas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I suppose this regex suits your rules...

```
var rules = /^[a-z](?=[a-z]*[0-9])[a-z0-9]{0,6}[a-z]$/;
```

But I think there are several issues with your code, which I'd like to point out. Don't take it as a personal offense, please: believe me, I'm actually saving you a LOT of time and nerves.

First, there's a standard rule: each function should do only one thing - but do it really well (or so they say, these perfectionists!). Your code is too tightly coupled with DOM extraction: I was really surprised when it failed to work when pasted in my environment! Only then I noticed that `document.forms` call. It's not really needed here: it's sufficient to build a function taking one parameter, then call this function with the value extracted somewhere else. This way, btw, you can easily separate the causes of errors: it would be either in DOM part, or within the function.

Second, Regexes are really very close to be considered first-class citizens in JavaScript (not so as in Perl, but still much closer than in some other languages). That means you can write the regex literals as is, and use it later - without new Regexp constructs.

With all that said, I'd write your code as...

```
function validatePassword(password) {
  var rules = /^[a-z](?=[a-z]*[0-9])[a-z0-9]{0,6}[a-z]$/;
  return rules.test(password);
}
```

... then use it by something like ...

```
var password = document.form1.subject.value;
alert( validatePassword(password) ? 'Success! :)' : 'Failure... :(' );
```

P.S. And yes, Riccardo is right: set too strict rules for passwords - and suffer the consequences of narrowing the range of search for an attacker. And it's quite easy to see the validation rules set in Javascript: even obfuscators won't help much.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the modified code:

```
function demoMatchClick(input) {
  var validString = /^[a-z](?=[a-z]*[0-9])[a-z0-9]{0,6}[a-z]$/;
  if (validString.test(input)) {
    alert("Successful match");
  } else {
    alert("No match");
  }
}


demoMatchClick("hello world");
```

validString variable is already a RegExp object and you can use it directly, additionally .test() method belongs to regex object not to string.